# Amazon Aurora RDS queries seem very slow - ideas?

Tags: mysqli, amazon-aurora

I am looking at moving an app to Amazon Aurora to host the database

However, it seems insanely slow compared to my old database (hosted on a VPS)

```
$time = microtime(true);
$query = "SELECT id from transactions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$res = $db->query($query);
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
$now = microtime(true);
echo ($now - $time);
```

This consistently gives a result of around 0.0001 on my old server, but 0.03 on the Amazon server.

The transactions table has around 750k rows, and is correctly indexed...

I restarted both MySql instances to get valid readings

I also noticed that if I put in a deliberately slow query, such as

```
SELECT * from transactions where hash != '1'
```

It seems to seize up the Amazon server, such that it won't accept or process any other queries unless I reboot it.

Is Amazon aurora any good, or should I look elsewhere? I was assuming it would work well out of the box...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottleneck here could very well be network. Aurora does not claim to give better latencies, it claims to give better throughput. If you benchmark the same query against an Aurora Cluster, you'll most likely see a much higher TPS in Aurora. You should be able to scale that up further by adding more replicas.

I'm not claiming that Aurora is the better choice, merely stating that you are not evaluating the product at its strong suit.

On that note,
The query time difference that you see does look surprising, for the data size that you report. Consider doing the following experiments:
1. Run the query a few times to warm up the buffer pool
2. Try the same query on a few instance types (given the data size, I don't think it would make any difference). 
3. Try running sysbench between the 2 setups and see how it looks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you... I ended up spending a huge amount of time benchmarking, and I used an EC2 instance in the same region to eliminate network issues as far as possible. Found that in some cases (with poor indexing) Aurora is very much slower than my old VPS. But with correct indexing, overall speed is slightly slower, but not by much... and Aurora adds a lot more failover capability. Standard RDS benched at a lot slower, so sticking with Aurora for now, and continuing to test. Thanks for your reply!